# Why is the C loop executing one more time than required?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I have taken a look at the question asked here : [Why does the "for" loop execute one more time than the body of the loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074687/why-does-the-for-loop-execute-one-more-time-than-the-body-of-the-loop)

But I couldn't understand that. I have just begun learning C on my own. And there is a for loop in a program that I am writing, that is executing 6 times instead of 5, and then its also ignoring the value entered the 6th time. But it still asks the user for the value for the 6th time.

```
for (int counter = 1; counter <= 5; ++counter)
    {
        scanf_s("%f\n", &mk);
        mk_total += mk;
    }
```

the variable mk has been initialized to 0 already. Here is the whole program :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[20];
    float mk = 0; // mk= marks scored out of 100
    float percentage, average, mk_total = 0; // mk_total = total marks
    char grade;

    printf("Enter your name : ");
    gets(name);

    printf("Enter your marks (out of 100) in 5 subjects repsectively :\n");

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= 5; ++counter)
    {
        scanf_s("%f\n", &mk);
        mk_total += mk;
    }

    percentage = (mk_total / 500) * 100;
    average = (mk_total / 5);

    if (average < 50)
        grade = 'F';
    if (average >= 50 && average < 60)
        grade = 'C';
    if (average >= 60 && average < 70)
        grade = 'B';
    if (average >= 70 && average < 80)
        grade = 'B+';
    if (average >= 80 && average < 90)
        grade = 'A';
    if (average >= 90 && average <= 100)
        grade = 'O';

    printf("Name of the Student : %s\n", name);
    printf("Total marks secured : %g\n", mk_total);
    printf("Percentage secured  : %g\n", percentage);
    printf("Grade secured       : %c\n", grade);

    return 0;
}
```

The output asks the user for input a 6th time even after entering 5 values each separated by the enter/return key on my keyboard. Is there any way to prevent this ? I just used the for loop because I thought it would be cool to add numbers and it would use less variables.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: A trailing `\n` in a `scanf` format string is almost always wrong. See the duplicate post for details. Try with it removed.

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you use `else if` (and reverse the order) you could simplify the grading. As in `if (average >= 90) { grade = 'O'; } else if (average >= 80) { ... } ... else { grade = 'F'; }`

Comment: Dividing a floating point value by 500 and multiplying again with 100 is the same as simply dividing by 5 – mathematically always exactly, with floating point potentially some rounding issues come into play, but that's probably neglectable in your case...